# How to get Googlecode SVN statistics

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, google-code

I have a google code repository and I would like to find some statistics, things like number of lines of code, number of commits etc.

I see that there is something called [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/) but this requires the log file from the repository.

Does anyone know how I can get repository statistics for a google code SVN repository, either by getting the log file, or perhaps a plugin for eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to register your project on [Ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net) (has been bought by Sourceforge.net) and add your Subversion repository as *Enlistment*. After some hours in which Ohloh downloads and analyzes the repository you and everybody else get some very nice charts about the development progress and some other statistical data.

Take for example the one for [Subversion itself](http://www.ohloh.net/p/subversion/analyses/latest).

Answer (score 0):

Try mirroring the SVN repository with [svnsync](http://www.google.co.il/search?q=svnsync), which should be included in your svn installation on most *nixes.

On Windows, download the [Slik SVN Subversion build](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download), which includes all "admin" executables including svnsync.